# What is the output of Javascript's "navigator.language" function?

Tags: javascript

Long story, but I'm curious about something. Is it possible that "*navigator.language*" in Javascript outputs a variable like "en-US,en;q=0.5"? If I remember correctly, the output would be "en-US" or something similar. The first example I provided is only returned from the Accept-Language header, right?

I have a website that has a list of free advertisements. The advertisements are ranked by points. Each time a website links a visitor to my website, their advertisements gets a point. There's custom software going around that manages to cheat/fake these visitors to my website to get fake points on their advertisement. Therefore I'm starting to log much information from the visitors, like IP addresses, countries, user agents, referers, but also browser language. Browser language is filled into hidden HTML input fields so I can log them to the system with PHP after form submission.

I noticed that "navigator.language" returns the "en-US" example for each and every advertisement (I'm talking about ten thousands of visitors), but one of the advertisements returns the "en-US,en;q=0.5" example. I think that is impossible, and have a good faith to believe that they're using software that fills in fake information into the hidden input field, but they're doing it wrong.

Am I correct? Is the only REAL output of "navigator.language" something similar to "en-US", "nl", "en-GB", etc., and can I consider this advertisement as a cheater?

Comment: `navigator.language` is supposed to return an RFC 4646 compliant value. Obviously `en-US;en;q=0.5` isn't. I'd therefore be surprised if `navigator.language` was returning such a value by itself. Do you log the user agent for the client? What browser are they reporting?

Comment: It's not part of the specification of JavaScript; it's a web browser thing. It's not supposed to be anything but a valid language tag, but Firefox causes the string to reflect the same value as the "Accept-Language" HTTP header, and that can be a string like the one you're seeing.

Comment: [See this documentation for the meaning of that string.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation#The_Accept-Language.3a_header)

Comment: The bottom line is that the unusual values probably tell you nothing.

Comment: @ Pointy, thank you! In the meantime I've compared the strings to user-agents. I'm seeing the string on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer. Strange, no?

Comment: @Pointy—strictly, the [*navigator* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.navigator) is part of JavaScript™, and is in the [*HTML 5* specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#the-navigator-object). The [*navigator.language*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#navigatorlanguage) property should return the preferred language as a [*BCP 47 language tag*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#dom-navigator-language).

Comment: @RobG It's an API defined in the HTML5 specification, but it's not part of JavaScript The Programming Language. You won't find any mention of it in [the JavaScript language spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) I do agree that it's *supposed* to be (according to the HTML5 spec) a BCP 47 string, but sometimes it's not.

Comment: @Point—I think you missed my splitting hairs between JavaScript™ and ECMAScript. You're right, it's not part of ECMAScript, but it is part of MDN's JavaScript™ and other browser implementations as well as HTML5. ;-) This is one of my bug bears with HTML5: it documents what browsers do and what they should do, without differentiating which is which (e.g. it documents a lot of DOM 0 without saying those bits are historical and hence have a higher likelihood of being different across browsers, like *navigator.language*).

Comment: @RobG I guess it depends on what one means by "part of". If those browser objects and APIs are "part of" JavaScript, what does it mean that they're not available in Node.js?